# Is there better way to shorten this Lambda expression's result selector?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server, lambda

I'm new in LINQ and Lambda expression. I'm not sure is there a way to shorten the result on this `o.z.cust.cust.cust.bintAccountNo`.  As you can see below, the more table needed to join the longer the resultselector `cust.cust.cust`.  Is there better way to shorten this Lambda expression's result selector?

**POCO**

```
public class Tbl1 
 {
        [Key] 
        public long bintAccountNo{ get; set; }
 }


 public class Tbl2
 {
        [Key] 
        public int id { get; set; }
        public long bintAccountNo{ get; set; }
 }


 public class Tbl3
 {
        [Key] 
        public int id { get; set; }
        public long bintAccountNo{ get; set; }
 }

 public class Tbl4
 {
        [Key] 
        public int id { get; set; }
        public long bintAccountNo{ get; set; }
        public int intPartner{ get; set; }
 }

 public class Tbl5
 {
        [Key] 
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int intPartner{ get; set; }
 }

var b = (Tbl1 
.GroupJoin(Tbl2, cust => cust.bintAccountNo, cust2 => cust2.bintAccountNo, (cust, cust2) => new  { cust = cust, cust2 = cust2 })
.SelectMany(cust => cust.cust2.DefaultIfEmpty(), (cust, cust2) => new { cust = cust.cust, cust2 = cust2 })
.GroupJoin(Tbl3, c => c.cust.bintAccountNo, cust3 => cust3.bintAccountNo, (cust, cust3) => new { cust = cust, cust3 = cust3 })
.SelectMany(c => c.cust3.DefaultIfEmpty(), (cust, cust3) => new { cust = cust.cust, cust3 })
.Join(Tbl4, c => c.cust.cust.bintAccountNo, bp => bp.bintAccountNo, (cust, bp) => new { cust = cust, bp = bp })
.Join(Tbl5, z => z.bp.intPartner, part => part.intPartner, (z, part) => new { z = z, part = part }))
.Select(o => new 
  {
      bintAccountNo = o.z.cust.cust.cust.bintAccountNo
  }
```

Comment: Where's `Tbl1` & friends coming from? Is there not a `DataContext`? Is this [tag:linq-to-sql] or linq-to-entities /[tag:entity-framework]? It would really help if you posted your actual real code; as it stands there's very little context here IMO.

Comment: Edited as above, is there a different between linq-to-sql and linq-to-entities when it's come to syntax?

Comment: At first glance no, but knowing which technology you're using can help recommend other approaches; e.g. with EF you should use *navigation properties* instead of joins... and seeing your edit it *does* look like you have POCO classes / entities here... and now I just saw "this is linq-to-sql" and I'm confused.

Comment: i'm getting nightmare on navigation properties as generated T-SQL is much more complex or not efficient than explicit way as above.

Comment: So it *is* Entity Framework then.

Comment: Ah, ok. But for me i still don't see much different between linq-to-sql or linq-to-entities :). Thanks. So anyway to shorten the .cust.cust.cust. Or is this the correct way to write?

Comment: You do have to be a bit careful with generated SQL, but giving up on navigation properties isn't the answer! With no abstraction (thinking in *entities* rather than *tables*) and no navigation properties, you're getting pretty much none of the benefits of an ORM.

Comment: May be i judge too early. I have some other thing not understand. If i have 3 tables, Let say TableA, TableB, TableC. TableA has navigation property of TableB and TableB has a navigation property of TableC. If use eager loading 'Include', i just want to select TableA and TableB data. How do i not select the TableC data. Because i saw the generated SQL send T-SQL to get data for TableC as well.

Answer (score 2):

#### Naming

Your entities / POCO classes have badly named members (assuming the entity names themselves aren't *really* named the way you've posted them), that break the C# naming conventions for public members - they should be `PascalCase`, ...and what's with the Hungarian notation? Also disemvoweling is never a great idea - call a table `Table` instead of `Tbl`, and we'll know you didn't mean *Team-Based-Learning*... whatever.

```
public class Table2
{
       [Key] 
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public long AccountNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

Entities are NOT database tables; they MAP to database tables, and they're *classes* - so they should follow the naming conventions for C# classes. If they're mapped to tables/columns on SQL Server with different names, you should use the appropriate `[Column("columnName")]` attributes (or fluent API configurations) to specify the mapping.

#### Convention over Configuration

Entity Framework is able to infer a lot of things from the way you name things. Having a property called `Id` in an entity type, is automagically inferred to be that type's `[Key]` - hence, the explicit attribute is redundant / noise, and should be removed.

`Tbl1` is breaking this convention. The `[Key]` field `bintAccountNo` should be called `Id`, and the table should be called `Account` - so when other related entities have a property named `AccountId`, Entity Framework knows that's a FK property.

#### Navigation Properties

One of the greatest things about EF is its ability to simplify the querying of complex relationships between entities, using *navigation properties*.

```
public class Account
{
    public long Id{ get; set; }
}

public class Table2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long AccountId { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

You mention in a comment that you find the generated T-SQL inefficient when you're using navigation properties; how exactly is it "inefficient"? It's *verbose*, yes, but that doesn't make it inefficient. Have you performance-profiled it? What's the bottleneck? Could you be missing indexes?

---

#### Your Query

I like that you're using the *method syntax*, but it's not clear what's being queries exactly, because the code you posted looks like it's querying the *type* itself:

```
var b = (Tbl1.GroupJoin(...));
```

One would expect something like this:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var result = context.Tbl1s.GroupJoin(...));
}
```

**GroupJoin**

This is where the *query syntax* gets handy, see [*what exactly is a group join*? on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15599143/1188513):

`Join` syntax:

```
from p in Parent
join c in Child on p.Id equals c.Id
select new { p.Value, c.ChildValue }
```

`GroupJoin` syntax:

```
from p in Parent
join c in Child on p.Id equals c.Id into g
select new { Parent = p, Children = g }
```

And that calls [`GroupJoin()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx) for you under the hood, and it's easier to mentally picture what your data looks like, I find.

I'm not quite clear on `GroupJoin` followed by `SelectMany` - why not just do a regular `Join` then?

Comment: I'm really appreciate your answer (it's long and details). It's really helps me when i'm in new database, as this isan existing database and we need to develop a new module, and understand it's better to follow the naming convention but that lead us to more confuse when we come to check field name between database field name and poco. That's is my thought to keep everything same.

Comment: But a POCO is *not* a database record! An ORM is an **abstraction** of the database...

Comment: I will keep that in mind and continue to improve. When i first touch ORM i used a tool (forgot what the name) generate all class/entities for me then i just use it. And i'm obviously still looking around for standard way to do it. Your tips is helpful! Really! Thanks.

Comment: For GroupJoin() with SelectMany, i somehow need perform CROSS JOIN WITH GROUP JOIN, please refer to LINQ_104 at this link http://linq101.nilzorblog.com/join-operators.php#group-join